# Invalid Adress Specified to RtlvalidateHeap in Destructor for doubly linked list

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linked-list, destructor, doubly-linked-list

I keep getting this error when I run my program.

```
HEAP[PA1.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00C40000, 00C48880 )
PA1.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

I narrowed it down to my destructor but, im not sure why its causing it.

```
List::~List()
{
    if (!nullptr) {
        Item* toDelete = Head;
        while (toDelete != NULL) {
            Item* next = toDelete->Next;

                delete toDelete;
            toDelete = next;
        }
    }
```

Edit: I see that my problem is in my constructors but, im not sure what i need to change. The error happens when i begin to do a deep copy. So my guess is that its the copy constructor.

```
List::List()
{
    Head = 0;
    Prev = 0;
    Next = 0;

}

List::~List()
{
    Item* move = Head;
    while (Head)
    {
        Head = move->Next;
        delete move;
        move = Head;
    }
}

List::List(const List& copy) 
{
    Head = copy.Head;
    Next= copy.Next;
    Prev= copy.Prev;


}

List& List::operator=(const List& t)
{
    Head = t.Head;
    Prev = t.Prev;
    Next = t.Next;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Programming gets a lot easier to understand when you realize that where a program crashes often has no relationship to where the bug is. Narrowing down the crash site is important, but it's often only the first clue in the mystery.

Answer (score 0):

While your code is not sufficient to conclude for sure, looking at the symptoms and your destructor,  it is highly probable that you did not respect the [rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

The rule of 3 tells you that if you need a specific destructor, for example because you have a pointer, you need to implement at least the copy constructor and the copy assignment.

Why ?

- You have a pointer  `Next` in your class.
- Somehow you allocate some memory and put the address in that pointer (because if you wouldn't , you wouldn't delete the pointed object at the end
- If you do not have a copy construction and a copy assignment, when ever you cpy a List element, you will copy its pointer as it is.  The first object to be deleted (e.g. a temporary object?) would delete the pointer.  And when the second object get destroyed, its destructor will delete a pointer that is already deleted.

Now if you do not like to take care of the rule of 3,  there is a better alternative: avoid using raw pointers.  Try to use `shared_ptr` instead. These pointer manage memory by themselves (e.g. deleting the object when it's no longer used). Including in case of copying and deleting the copy.